# Mail.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar Classpath

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to install a Java Servlets based web application on a public server. The application demands that I place the mail.jar file and mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar file in my jdk/jre/lib/ext path. But I do not have access to this folder. Is there some other standard place where I can copy these files ?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, it should not be necessary to place them there. If your application needs them, it should suffice to place them in WEB-INF/lib inside your webapp. That is the standard place for your app specific libraries.